# How can I count two things in a query?

Tags: php, eloquent

I'm wondering how can I count total rows, while counting the total amount??

here's my code

```
    $total_sales = $this->db->table('order_payment')
    ->selectRaw('*, sum(order_payment.amount) as total_amount, order_header.*')
    ->leftjoin('order_header', 'order_header.order_id', '=', 'order_payment.order_id')
    ->where(DB::raw('Date(reference_date)'), $sales_date)
    ->where('order_header.order_type_id', '2')
    ->get();
```

[Here's My Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmJYT.png)

i currently getting the total amount, what i can't get is the total of the `order_type_id` row ..

hoping that anyone can help me. (sorry for my poor English)

Answer (score 0):

Can you change

`sum(order_payment.amount) as total_amount, ...`

to

`sum(order_payment.amount) as total_amount, sum(order_type_id) as total_order_type_id, ...`